# Find position of first value greater than X in a vector

Tags: r, vector, position, max

I have a vector and want to find the position of the first value that is greater than 100.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
# Randomly generate a suitable vector
set.seed(0)
v <- sample(50:150, size = 50, replace = TRUE)

min(which(v > 100))
```

Answer (score 35):

Most answers based on `which` and `max` are slow (especially for long vectors) as they iterate through the *entire* vector:

1. `x>100` evaluates ***every*** value in the vector to see if it matches the condition
2. `which` and `max`/`min` search *all* the indexes returned at step 1. and find the maximum/minimum

`Position` will only evaluate the condition until it encounters the first TRUE value and immediately return the corresponding index, without continuing through the rest of the vector.

```
# Randomly generate a suitable vector
v <- sample(50:150, size = 50, replace = TRUE)

Position(function(x) x > 100, v)
```

Comment: `^` for functional programming

Comment: Side note: `?Position` says: _"The current implementation is not optimized for performance."_ So I guess it also evaluates the whole vector.

Comment: @lukeA - it uses a for loop. If you just run "Position" (the bare name) it will print out the implementation.

Comment: @user295691 and evaluates the function every time, both slow operations in R. Unless you specifically expect the match to occur at the beginning of the vector, I'd guess this is likely going to be slower than the vectorized version.

Answer (score 16):

Check out `which.max`:

```
x <- seq(1, 150, 3)
which.max(x > 100)
# [1] 35
x[35]
# [1] 103
```

Comment: `?which.max`: 'However, match(FALSE, x) or match(TRUE, x) are typically preferred, as they do indicate mismatches.' => `match(TRUE, x>100)`

Answer (score 6):

Just to mention, Hadley Wickham has implemented a function, `detect_index`, to do exactly this task in his `purrr` package for functional programming.

I recently used `detect_index` myself and would recommend it to anyone else with the same problem.

Documentation for `detect_index` can be found here: https://rdrr.io/cran/purrr/man/detect.html

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: For example, `purrr::detect_index(seq(1, 150, 3), function(x) x > 100)`. Hadley's packages are optimized for readability, but certainly not for speed.

Answer (score 3):

As I need to perform a similar calculation many times within a loop, I was interested in which of the many answers provided in this thread would be most efficient.

**TLDR:**
Whether the first value appears early or late in a vector, `which.max(v > 100)` is the fastest solution to this problem.

Note, however, that if no entry in `v` exceeds 100, it will return 1; thus there may be cause for

```r
SafeWhichMax <- function (v) {
  first <- which.max(v > 100)
  if (first == 1L && v[1] <= 100) NA else first
}
SafeWhichMax(100) # NA
SafeWhichMax(101) # 1
```

If a vector is very long and is not guaranteed to contain any `TRUE` results, `match(TRUE, v > 100)` may be quicker than `which.max()` with checks.

```r
# Short vector:
v <- 0:105

microbenchmark(
  which.max(v > 100),
  match(TRUE, v > 100),
  min(which(v > 100)),
  which(v > 100)[1],
  Position(function(x) x, v > 100),
  Position(function(x) x > 100, v),
  purrr::detect_index(v, function (x) x > 100)
)
```

```
Unit: microseconds
                                  mean      median
which.max(v > 100)                24.112    23.80
SafeWhichMax(v)                   24.889    24.25
match(TRUE, v > 100)              34.752    33.20
min(which(v > 100))               25.506    25.20
which(v > 100)[1]                 25.320    24.90
Position(function(x) x, v > 100)  3231.783  3043.50
Position(function(x) x > 100, v)  3487.805  3314.75
purrr::detect_index               16436.579 16064.90
```

```r
# Long vector, with late first occurrence of v > 100
v <- -10000:105
```

```
Unit: microseconds
                                  mean   median
which.max(v > 100)               24.958    24.30
SafeWhichMax(v)                  25.456    24.90
match(TRUE, v > 100)             37.680    37.85
min(which(v > 100))              26.439    26.00
which(v > 100)[1]                25.724    25.55
Position(function(x) x, v > 100) 3224.240  3036.50
Position(function(x) x > 100, v) 3389.538  3287.05
purrr::detect_index              17344.706 15283.35
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions, another is:

```
x <- 90:110
which(x > 100)[1]
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming values is your vector.

```
 firstGreatearThan <- NULL
  for(i in seq(along=values)) { 
    if(values[i] > 100) {
       firstGreatearThan <- i
       break
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think that would give you the first value unless you added a `break`

Comment: and we don't need a loop here

Comment: Yeah, right. The point is that is a so simple question, I just wrote a faster answer