# For each value of one column, find which is the last value of another vector that is lower

Tags: r

Finding the last position of a vector that is less than a given value is fairly straightforward (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388334/r-find-position-of-first-value-greater-than-x-in-a-vector)

But, doing this line by line for a column in a data.frame or data.table is horribly slow.  For example, we can do it like this (which is ok on small data, but not good on big data)

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
x = sort(sample(20,5))
# [1]  6  8 15 16 17
y = data.table(V1 = 1:20)

y[, last.x := tail(which(x <= V1), 1), by = 1:nrow(y)]
#     V1 last.x
# 1:   1     NA
# 2:   2     NA
# 3:   3     NA
# 4:   4     NA
# 5:   5     NA
# 6:   6      1
# 7:   7      1
# 8:   8      2
# 9:   9      2
# 10: 10      2
# 11: 11      2
# 12: 12      2
# 13: 13      2
# 14: 14      2
# 15: 15      3
# 16: 16      4
# 17: 17      5
# 18: 18      5
# 19: 19      5
# 20: 20      5
```

Is there a fast, vectorised way to get the same thing? Preferably using data.table or base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `findInterval`

```
y[ , last.x := findInterval(V1, x)]
```

---

Slightly more convoluted using `cut`. But on the other hand, you get the `NA`s right away:

```
y[ , last.x := as.numeric(cut(V1, c(x, Inf), right = FALSE))]
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty simple in base R

```
x<-c(6L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 17L)
y<-1:20
cumsum(y %in% x)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: This may work in the simple case in OP, but try `y <- c(7, 9, 18)`

Comment: Truth! Not knowing about `findInterval()` function I probably would have done something like this to your newly posed problem `apply(sapply(y,">",x),2,sum)`