# Optimizing order vector searching in R

Tags: r, optimization, vector

I have a problem:

```
times <- c('2020-06-26 10:00', '2020-06-26 10:10', '2020-06-26 10:11', '2020-06-26 10:15',
'2020-06-26 10:16','2020-06-26 10:17') #large, ordered vector
dateTimeToCheck1 <- '2020-06-26 10:12'
dateTimeToCheck2 <- '2020-06-26 10:16'
result <- times < dateTimeToCheck2 & times > dateTimeToCheck1
```

In ordered vector, I would like to compare each element with constant values. What is the most efficient way to do it, knowing that vector is ordered?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
times <- as.POSIXct(c('2020-06-26 10:00', '2020-06-26 10:10', '2020-06-26 10:11', '2020-06-26 10:15',
           '2020-06-26 10:16','2020-06-26 10:17')) #large, ordered vector
dateTimeToCheck1 <- as.POSIXct('2020-06-26 10:12')
dateTimeToCheck2 <- as.POSIXct('2020-06-26 10:16')

times[which(times < dateTimeToCheck2)]
# [1] "2020-06-26 10:00:00 GMT"
# [2] "2020-06-26 10:10:00 GMT"
# [3] "2020-06-26 10:11:00 GMT"
# [4] "2020-06-26 10:15:00 GMT"

times[which(times > dateTimeToCheck1)]
# [1] "2020-06-26 10:15:00 GMT"
# [2] "2020-06-26 10:16:00 GMT"
# [3] "2020-06-26 10:17:00 GMT"

# EDIT
times[which(times > dateTimeToCheck1 & times < dateTimeToCheck2)]
# [1] "2020-06-26 10:15:00 GMT"
```

Comment: Not really. I don't want to compare each element but somehow use the fact, that the vector is ordered

Comment: Excpected output is the same as in last line of my code. But I want to achieve it in an efficient way, assuming that vector is large and ordered.

Comment: But we are still comparing each element of vector element, aren't we?

Comment: `which()` compares them to `dateTimeToCheck1` and `dateTimeToCheck2`. What specific date/s from the 6 possible in `times` would you like for `results` to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can check: [Find position of first value greater than X in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388334/find-position-of-first-value-greater-than-x-in-a-vector/29388546)

and try something like this:

```
l <- Position(function(x) x > dateTimeToCheck1, times)
r <- Position(function(x) x >= dateTimeToCheck2, times) - 1

lgl_vec <- rep(FALSE, length(times))

true_indices <- if(is.na(l)){
    NULL
  } else if(is.na(r)) {
    l:length(times)
  } else {
    l:r
  }

lgl_vec[true_indices] <- TRUE
```

**OUTPUT**

```
lgl_vec
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Read about `right` parameter in `?Position` it might reduce number of operations if you know to which edge your `dateTimeToCheck` are closer to (start/end).

**OTHER APPROACH**

Insted of using `Position` twice you can write your own loop (or function) for finding `l` and `r`:

```
l_found <- r_found <- FALSE
for(i in seq_along(times)){
  
  if(!l_found && times[[i]] > dateTimeToCheck1){
    l <- i
    l_found <- TRUE
  }

  if(!r_found && times[[i]] >= dateTimeToCheck2){
    r <- i - 1
    r_found <- TRUE
    break()
  }
}
```